# Docker pull images No such host error on mac osx

Tags: macos, docker

I recently installed latest docker on my mac and i'm getting following error on pulling images.

First I install latest docker form mac binary and then i run

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

And it return

```
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: Error while pulling image:
Gethttps://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/nginx/images: dial tcp:
lookup index.docker.io on ***.***.**.*:**: no such host
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: You shoudl really avoid posting picture for a question. Especially when it's partially transparent, moreover when it's for reading text. There are many reasons you should avoid it among which: readability and impaired access. You should also add a clear question, what is the problem, and what you tried. Overall, you may gain reading the BP of SO ;)

Comment: [I found what I was looking for](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5321002) :)

Comment: I edited my question. can you help me now please

Comment: Does the command `docker pull nginx` work?

Comment: @Auzias it work but while pulling the image it show the same error :

Comment: @Auzias It shows the following error.

    Error: Service 'nginx' failed to build: Get     https://registry1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/nginx/tags/alpine: dial tcp:    lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.xx.x:xx: no such host

Comment: What is this registry: "registry1.docker.io" ? It is not resolvable, it mostly due to this. Did you change anything on the Docker configuration? Does your firewall disable some download type?

Comment: @Auzias My firewall is turned off and i didn't changed any configuration. I just downloaded it from docker website and installed. Is there any helpful solution?

Comment: Now i completely uninstall the application and reinstall it again. and this command works fine :

    docker run hello-world
but when i try another commands eg:

docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx

then it shows the following error:

docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/nginx/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on xxx.xxx.xx.x:xx: no such host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days research I can't get the actual solution so i did one trick and worked for me. what i done is I open the docker preferences and there is a option reset to factory defaults and i reset my docker but it deletes all my containers and images after all it works. Thanks everyone.